# Compute $\frac{L'(\chi,s)}{L(\chi,s)}$.

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let $\chi$ a character of Dirichlet mod $q$ and $$L(\chi,s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$$
where $\Re(s)>1$. I recall that $\frac{f'}{f}:=\log(f)'$. I want to compute $-\frac{L'}{L}$. So,

$$-\frac{L'(\chi,s)}{L(\chi,s)}=\left(\log\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}\right)\right)'=\frac{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(p)\chi(n)}{n^s}}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}},$$

but how can I get something like $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}\ \ ?$$
Because I'm suppose to arrive to something like that.

Comment: Perhaps you can adopt https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithmic_Derivative_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Euler product:
$$L(\chi,s)=\prod_p\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}\right)^{-1}.$$
Using logarithmic differentiation gives
$$\frac{L'(\chi,s)}{L(\chi,s)}=\sum_p(\ln p)\frac{\chi(p)/p^s}{1-\chi(p)/p^s}=\sum_p\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p)^n\ln p}{p^{ns}}.
$$

Comment: @user380364 Also if $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}, \frac{F'(s)}{F(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}$ and $F_\chi(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\chi(n) n^{-s}$ then $\displaystyle\frac{F_\chi'(s)}{F_\chi(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\chi(n) n^{-s}$ whenever $\chi$ is completely multiplicative

Comment: @user1952009: Thanks, and how do you prove that ?

Comment: @user380364 It is true for $F(s) \mapsto F(s)^k$ and $F(s) \mapsto (1-F(s))^k$ thus by linearity also for  $F(s) \mapsto \log(F(s))= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1-F(s))^k}{k}$ and $F(s) \mapsto \frac{F'(s)}{F(s)}$

Comment: There is a slight mistake. There should be a negative sign in front of $\dfrac{L'(\chi,s)}{L(\chi, s)}$